# How to inject dependency in to a class in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, class, dependency-injection, dependencies

I want to use ngx translate inside a static class in my class. How can I do this? How to do dependency injection in a singleton class?

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    static instance: MyService;

    static getInstance() {
        if (MyService.instance) {
            return MyService.instance;
        }

        MyService.instance = new MyService();
        return MyService.instance;
    }

    constructor() {
        if (!MyService.instance) {
             MyService.instance = this;
        }

        return MyService.instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [**Singleton services**](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services). Angular has already got you covered, since Singleton are managed internally by the DI Container. The instance will be created only one time, and injecting `MyService` in another component will be equivalent to your `MyService.getInstance()`.

You just need to set `providedIn` scope for your service to `"root"`:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: i cannot do it because am using the MyService.methodname in a constant.  and the method is a static method.How can i get the service instance inside the static method

Comment: You can't use Dependency Injection into a constant, that would be impossible since DI may still be not initialized. You should rework the place where you are defining the constant and transform it into a Service and so on